# Hiding array items in a foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a list of items drawn from a file on my server.

I'm hiding certain filenames as you can see in my code, but the variable i'm using "$filelist" is only hiding the last value in the array instead of all the values.

As you can see in the image below A15 and A17 should be hidden, but only A17 is.

How can I use $filelist to hide all the values within it, rather than only the last one?

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $filelist = $row["file"];
     echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$filelist\" name=\"files[]\" checked=\"checked\"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;$filelist<br />";
}

echo "<br>";

$dirname = "/var/www/vhosts/public_html/forms/templates";
$forms = scandir($dirname);

sort($forms);

foreach ($forms as $file) {

if(($file != ".") and
   ($file != "..") and
   ($file != "index.php") and
   ($file != "Site Induction Sheet.docx") and
   ($file != "Method Statement Complete.docx") and
   ($file != "Construction Phase Plan Complete.docx") and
   ($file != "Method Statement.docx") and
   ($file != "Construction Phase Plan.docx") and 
   ($file != $filelist))

   {
       echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$file\" name=\"files[]\" />&nbsp;&nbsp;$file<br />";
   }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add file name that you want to hide to `$filelist` array and then check if `$file` is in that array using `in_array`

```
$filelist = [];
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $filelist[] = $file = $row["file"];
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$file\" name=\"files[]\" checked=\"checked\"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;$file<br />";
}
$filelist[] = ".";
$filelist[] = "..";
$filelist[] = "index.php";
$filelist[] = "Site Induction Sheet.docx";
$filelist[] = "Method Statement Complete.docx";
$filelist[] = "Construction Phase Plan Complete.docx";
$filelist[] = "Method Statement.docx";
$filelist[] = "Construction Phase Plan.docx";
echo "<br>";
$dirname = "/var/www/public_html/forms/templates";
$forms = scandir($dirname);
sort($forms);
foreach ($forms as $file) {
    if (!in_array($file, $filelist)) {
        echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$file\" name=\"files[]\" />&nbsp;&nbsp;$file<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: A15 and A17 are now removed from the main list, but at the top they both show "Array" instead of their values.

Comment: Fixed. Try now :)

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I've been trying to do that all day :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `$filelist` is not a list, it's just the last item of the list. You can use the `in_array()` way seen in the other answer, or the `! isset()` way here:

```
$file_seen = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $file = $row["file"];
     echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$file\" name=\"files[]\" checked=\"checked\"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;$file<br />";
     $file_seen[ $file ] = true;
}

…

foreach ($forms as $file) {
  if( … and
    ( ! isset( $file_seen[ $file ])
  ){
       echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$file\" name=\"files[]\" />&nbsp;&nbsp;$file<br />";
   }
}
```